# Cakephp Associations Not Working

Tags: cakephp

Hello there,
             thanks in adv for help.

i have two table: named as options fields are (id,option_title,created,status) and second table as option values fields as (id,option value,options_id,created,status). THe option values table has a foreign key as options_id. Now when i created association between these two table . i didn't work.. Let me explain you how i am creating association.

```
   In the Option model i am using following code.

     var $hasMany = array(
    'values' => array(
        'className' => 'Optionvalue',
        'foreignKey' => 'options_id'
    ));

     But this is not working and  i am not able to get data from options table. Can any please advice me.. where i am wrong. I just need options table data in the optionsvalue add view file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a table called options and another called optionvalues. Here is how the Option model looks like

```
    class Option extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
            'Optionvalue' => array(
                'className' => 'Optionvalue',
                'foreignKey' => 'option_id',
                'dependent' => FALSE
            )
);

    }
```

In the Optionvalue model you then go like this

```
class Optionvalue extends AppModel {
   public $belongsTo = array(
        'Option' => array(
            'className' => 'Option',
            'foreignKey' => 'option_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

    }
```

This is how it should look like. In the Optionvalue Add method, you will need to write this in the view

```
echo $this->Form->create('Optionvalue');
echo $this->Form->input('option_id');
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

and the options will appear by themselves.
Very important though, you did not follow the naming conventions. `options_id` needs to be `option_id` among others.

Comment: elha thankx for your reply. this really helped me.. Many Thankx.. Tc

Answer (score 0):

Use 
**option_id** in place of 'options_id'

Cakephp strongly follows naming conventions.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Also looks like you are not using proper naming conventions for other places too.

Comment: No brother . it didn't worked i changed the field name to option_id , but not worked. :(